# Need help for naming a switch on our website

Tags: toggle, marketing, learning

I need help for naming a switch on our website.

Our company provides online education services. On our website, learners can view learning materials and content. The learning materials and content come with complete learning highlights and notes.

[image]

For one of the learning sections, the teacher is able turn on/off the learning highlights and notes. By doing so, the teacher assigns a 'special mode' which would only display highlights and notes the teacher would like students to learn.

My question is, how would you give a name to describe such a switch?

Would you call it a 'learning mode' or a 'key mode' in learning? Is there any better way to describe it?

Comment: Welcome to UXSE Lin! Can you make it clearer the two different modes? As I understand you have 1) a general overview of learning material and 2) a mode which shows only the highlights selected by the teacher. Is that correct?

Comment: What phrases do your learners use? Have you spoken with users to understand the language they use to talk about your services?

Answer (score 1):

Best case scenario is that you name it in a way that makes users know what will happen when they use this switch.

I think "Learning mode" is fine in this case, you could provide an explanation in form of a tooltip with an information-icon next to the name to make it more transparent for people that never used the feature or are unaware.

Answer (score 1):

'Learning mode' is a bit vague. Does change how you interact? Does it hide stuff or show more? Does it change the layout? Is it a completely new interface (e.g. you have a normal list of words to read, and learning mode turns it in to multiplr-choice questions or fill-in-tye-blanks). It's just not a very descriptive name.

What about 'annotations' or 'teachers notes'? Those both clarify that the overall thing stays the same, but it adds small snippets of text.

Also, consider migrating to https://english.stackexchange.com since it's more of a language question than an UI one.

Answer (score 0):

You could call it "Learning Mode" as there doesn't seem to be much wrong in that term.

Just make sure that there are enough visual queues that inform the user that their current experience is changing.  This will enable the user to get into the correct mental mode.